# Multiple columns in Cassandra tables

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am wondering what happens when there are multiple Non-PK columns in a table. I've read this example:
http://johnsanda.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/why-i-am-ready-to-move-to-cql-for.html

Which shows that with single column:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_metrics (
schedule_id int,
time timestamp,
value double,
PRIMARY KEY (schedule_id, time)
);
```

We get:

[image]

Now I wonder what happens when we have two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_metrics (
schedule_id int,
time timestamp,
value1 double,
value2 int,
PRIMARY KEY (schedule_id, time)
);
```

Are we going to end up with something like:

```
row key  columns...
123      1339707619:"value1" | 1339707679:"value2" | 1339707784:"value2"
...
```

or rather:

```
row key  columns...
123      1339707619:"value1":"value2" | 1339707679:"value1":"value2" | 1339707784:"value1""value2"
...
```

etc. I guess what I am asking is if this is going to be a **sparse** table given that I only insert "value1" or "value2" at a time.

In such situations if I want to store more columns (one per each type, eg. double, int, date, etc) would it be better perhaps to have separate tables rather than storing everything in a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post might help in explaining what is happening when composite keys are created:
[Cassandra Composite Columns - How are CompositeTypes chosen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218868/cassandra-composite-columns-how-are-compositetypes-chosen?rq=1)

So essentially the table will look in the following way:

```
row key  columns...
123      1339707619:"value1" | 1339707679:"value2" | 1339707784:"value2"
```

See also reference to secondary indexes:
http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/SecondaryIndexes